# Is it possible to simulate an increased rate of passage of time in Android?

Tags: android

I searched for a while, but couldn't find the same question.

I am writing an application where I need to schedule a lot of alarms a day, and then do different things throughout the day, and I'd love to be able to test, say 24 hours in 24 minutes, or something along those lines.

**Is it possible to simulate a faster passage of time, either in emulator, or on-device?**

If it is, this would be great for me to be able to test these things without losing development time. As it is, I'm writing them in a way that I think will work, doing spot tests, and then running the program myself to verify that the behavior is correct, but it greatly slows my development time to have to wait a day or two between seeing a poor behavior, and then trying to fix it and retesting it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why can't you just schedule your alarms within seconds of each other?

Comment: Then I'd have to have a debug set of logic, and a real set of logic. That approach works for small sets where I just want to make sure that I didn't mess up something as far as scheduling them goes, but when it comes to testing actual behavior I would like to avoid this if all possible. Another reason is that I want different behaviors on different days (think weekdays vs weekend). I would like to test the logic I've written instead of playing with constants like FORCE_IS_WEEKEND.

Comment: Another reason - I'd like to be able to test (via simulating the speedy passage of time) that my alarm that is supposed to fire "at midnight" works.

Comment: I suspect that to do this you would need to much with the timer in your own custom kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you abstract all time-dependent tasks into a single class, you could inherit that into a test-class, where all system times are multiplied by some constant, and all user times are divided by some constant. Instead of calling any time-dependent methods directly, you call it trough this class.

```
class TimeHandler {
    protected Context context;

    public TimeHandler(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public long toSystemMillis(long userMillis) {
        return userMillis;
    }
    public long toUserMillis(long systemMillis) {
        return systemMillis;
    }
    public long toSystemDelay(long userDelay) {
        return userDelay;
    }
    public long toUserDelay(long systemDelay) {
        return systemDelay;
    }

    public void setAlarmAt(long userMillis, PendingIntent operation) {
        long systemMillis = toSystemMillis(userMillis);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, systemMillis, operation);
    }

    public void setAlarmAfter(long userDelay, PendingIntent operation) {
        long systemDelay = toSystemDelay(userDelay);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, systemDelay, operation);
    }
} // (scroll down)

class OptimizedTimeHandler extends TimeHandler {
    protected static final long RATE = 60; // 1 minute -> 1 hour
    protected static final long START_TIME = Date.UTC(2011,9,18,0,0,0);

    public TestTimeHandler(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public long toSystemMillis(long userMillis) {
        return START_TIME + (userMillis - START_TIME)/RATE;
    }
    @Override
    public long toUserMillis(long systemMillis) {
        return START_TIME + (userMillis - START_TIME)*RATE;
    }
    @Override
    public long toSystemDelay(long userDelay) {
        return userDelay/RATE;
    }
    @Override
    public long toUserDelay(long systemDelay) {
        return systemDelay*RATE;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You could make the `RATE` and `START_TIME` constants into instance fields. Maybe even constructor arguments.

Example usage:

```
TimeHandler th = new TimeHandler();
th.setAlarmAt(Date.UTC(2011,9,19,0,0,0), operation);
// will fire at 2011-09-19 00:00:00 (real time)

th = new OptimizedTimeHandler();
th.setAlarmAt(Date.UTC(2011,9,19,0,0,0), operation);
// will fire at 2011-09-18 00:24:00 (real time)
```

If you can't control the actual scheduling of the alarms, I don't think there is any way to compress the time. You will have to use these classes to schedule the alarms when you are reading it from the database.

Comment: This doesn't work, because I need to do some things at a specific time each day, say, midnight, but I want to verify that my timings are correct without it BEING midnight when I run the test.

Comment: I see. I appreciate your help. As of right now, I think the answer is that no, there is no way to goad the system clock. Thanks for the proposed solution!